# AJAX Json get data from PHP with for loop

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have got this AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../connect.php',
    data: "OrB=" + ajaxsend+"&&IOr="+i,
    success: function(data)
    { 
        var x = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            var el='<div class="Ordb">\
            <img src="../users/'+x[i][0]+'">\
            <span>'+x[i][1]+'</span>\
            <span class="s2">'+x[i][2]+'</span>\
            </div>'
            $(".F_W_comments").children().remove();
            $(".F_W_comments").html(el);
        } 
    }
});
```

And this php

```
if (isset($_GET['OrB'])) {
    $OB=$_GET['OrB'];
    $I=$_GET['IOr'];
    if ($OB=='OO') {
        $OB='`Date` ASC';
    }else if ($OB=='No') {
        $OB='`Date` DESC';
    }
    $query=$con->query("SELECT id,comment FROM uploads WHERE Rand='$I'");
    $row=$query->fetch_row();
    $Commentsq=$con->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Post_id='$row[0]' ORDER BY $OB LIMIT 4") or die($con->error);
    $commenters = array();
    while ($CommentRow=$Commentsq->fetch_row()) {
        $CommenterPp=$con->query("SELECT Profile_pic FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$CommentRow[3]'");        
        $CommenterPicture=$CommenterPp->fetch_row();
        $CommenterPp=$con->query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Id='$CommentRow[3]'");        
        $CommenterName=$CommenterPp->fetch_row();
        $commenters[] = array($CommenterPicture,$CommenterName,$CommentRow[1]); 
    }
    echo json_encode($commenters);
}
```

My problem is AJAX gives me error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Pointing this line

```
<img src="../users/'+x[i][0]+'">\
```

Also i get 1 element returned instead of 4.Have i got any mistake in my code because it is working wrong

Comment: I think you forgot to a terminator `;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly What is the difference?

Comment: Thanks!But it did not help:( @Fil

Comment: Actually I am wrong, ignore me

Comment: Show us what is returned in the `data` parameter

Comment: have you not try to put <img> inline not in new line

Comment: @RiggsFolly It returns div with Json inside

Comment: @Fil Why would i wanna do that?

Comment: It returns an OBJECT containing an array, not just an array

Comment: Show us an `echo json_encode($commenters);`, I cannot picture what will be produced in my mind but that would be helpful

Comment: Because this part \ violate the syntax, its more clear if like this `var el='<div class="Ordb"><img src="../users/'+x[i][0]+'"><span>'+x[i][1]+'</span><span class="s2">'+x[i][2]+'</span></div>';`

Answer (score 0):

First, change your JavaScript. Never hardcode the length of a for loop when looping over an array. Use i < x.length instead of i <= 4. Btw; i <= 4 loops 5 times, so if you expect an array of length 4 to come back, you'll go over the length of your array anyway; this will throw the same error (not defined).

I don't know why your PHP script is returning only 1 element, I can't see your database. If you put a console.log(x) just after assigning x, you'll see the result in your browser console.

I suggest too that you place the values in the PHP code in an associative array, this makes the returned JSON on the client side better to read (and less prone to error):

```
$commenters[] = array('picture' => $CommenterPicture, 'name' => $CommenterName,.....);
```

Comment: What should i change in JSON after assigning php array like this?It gives undefined in everything in JSON

Comment: If you're setting up your JSON like this, you could access the values with x[i].picture and x[i].name instead of x[i][0] and x[i][1], which makes the code much more readable.

Comment: But my problem is it should return 4 divs but it returns only 1.When i have divs 1 2 3 4 it should return "1 2 3 4 ",but returns "4" only and when i have 6 5 4 3 it only returns "3"